Efficiently reading part of partitioned dataset
I have pretty big (up to ~300Gb) datasets stored by partitions in parquet format (compressed).
I'm trying to find an efficient way to read parts (as defined by a set of filters) of the dataset into pandas.
The way it's done now is
result = ds.dataset(dataset_storage_root, format="parquet", partitioning='hive').scanner(
    columns=columns,
    filter=filters
).to_table().to_pandas()

Although this works, it's rather slow (I assume this is due to the fact it actually reads the full dataset and only then applies filters, iterating over each row).
And by rather slow I mean ~13 seconds, which is OK given the dataset size, but ridiculous given the actual amount of data I need to retrieve.
Manually determining the subfolder for the data and reading just this part takes ~9ms for comparison. The downside is I need to manually add partition columns and values and handle quite a few corner cases with filtering and schemas.
I would imagine there must be a way to do this via API and efficiently at that.
What I've already tried to my disappointment:
df_pandas = pd.read_parquet(dataset_storage_root, engine="pyarrow", filters=filters)

Takes 1m 23s
df_pq = pq.read_table(dataset_storage_root, filters=filters)

Takes 1m 22s
These take insane amount of time despite the claim is it should only read the subset specified by filters.

fastparquet is big data work-flows aimed support for Parquet file format, does support filtering and could be used to create pandas.DataFrame,
please test if it is acceptably fast for your use case.

Tried it, but unfortunately it's not faster and it requires homogeneous data, which is not the case for me (the columns specified are guaranteed to be there, but some partitions can have additional columns).

Filtering will use both partition information and parquet statistics. Some things to try:

add a partition key filter, even if it is redundant with the actual field being searched
reuse the dataset, because it first scans to cache statistics and can itself be slow

dataset = ds.dataset(dataset_storage_root, format="parquet", partitioning='hive')
dataset.to_table(columns=columns, filters & (pc.field("a_key") == ...))
dataset.to_table(columns=columns, filters & (pc.field("another_key") == ...))


The problem is that it's the ds.dataset() which takes the overwhelming portion of the execution time, and I'm not sure how an existing object will (or will not, I guess) handle changes in the underlying data between to_table() calls.
